# highest power of 2 behind a number

Tags: c++

I am writing a code to give numbers in a line and the inputs finish with zero then wirtes the highest power of 2 smaller or equal the inputs in a line.
it doesn't work.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int highestPowerof2( int n)
{
  static int result = 0;

  for (static int i=n; i>=1; i--)
  {
    if ((i & (i-1)) == 0)
    {
      result = i;
      break;
    }
  }
  return result;
}

int main() {

  static int num ;
  do{
    cin>>num ;
  }
  while(num=!0);

  cout<<highestPowerof2(num)<<"\n";
  return 0;

}
```

Comment: what is the highest power of 2? You mean highest power of 2 smaller or equal than `n` ?

Comment: please dont edit the answer to fix your code after you got answers (or better not at all). Your edit completely invalidated my answer. I rolled the edit back

Comment: What you can do is write EDIT at the end of your current post and provide the new version of your program, mentioning that the modification is based on xxx's answer. It is important to give details on the "non working" symptoms

Comment: @Damien I can only speak for myself, but I dislike this "EDIT" procedure almost as much as editing the original content. If there is a new question a new question should be opened. Questions are not really meant to contain some history of fixes. Suppose what happens when OP follows your suggestion and then I decide to delete my answer...

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 What I understood from OP's comment is that the programme still does not work after the corrections you mentioned. OP might have not implemented them correctly, or there might be another error. I understand than the EDIT mode is not perfect but then how to proceed ? A new question has some drawbacks too

Comment: @Damien the question is unclear to begin with (at least to me). Adding the input, output and expected output to the question would not alter the scope of the question at all, but would make it more answerable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another approach that is a little bit faster for large `n`. For example if `n = 2^31 - 1`, then the original loop would need to iterate 2^30 - 1 = 1,073,741,823 times, whereas this loop only needs a single iteration (provided `sizeof(int) == 4`):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int highestPowerof2( int n)
{
    if (n < 0) return 0;
    int result = 0;
    int num_bits = sizeof(int) * 8;
    unsigned int i = 1 << (num_bits - 1);
    while(i > 0) {
        if (n >= i) return i;
        i >>= 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    int num ;
    while (1) {
        cin >> num;
        cout << highestPowerof2(num) << "\n";
        if (num == 0) break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The most surprising thing in your code is this:

```
do{
   cin>>num ;
 }
 while(num=!0);
```

You keep reading `num` from user input until `num == 0`. I have to admit that I dont really understand the rest of your code, but for `num == 0` calling the function `highestPowerof2(num)` will always result in `0`.

Perhaps you wanted to repeat the program until the user decides to quit, that could be

```
do{
   cin>>num ;
   cout<<highestPowerof2(num)<<"\n";
} while(num=!0);
```

PS: the other "surprising" thing is that you use `static` in places where it does not really make sense. Better simply remove it.

Comment: @micheal what is "it" and what is the meaning of "didn't work" ?